# Access to vmware shared folder from linux guest

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I am running a linux distro in my wmware and I wanted to share some file between my guest (linux zeroshell) and my host (windows 8.1).

For this I saw that there is an option in wmware in Virtual Machine Setting-> Options->SharedFolders and I added in there one folder C:/mysharedfolder.

Now I wonder how I can access to this folder from my linux guest.

```
cd <path>
```

What to use as path?

Thanks

Comment: If VMware tools are installed, you should see the shared folder as an additional disk in the VM.

Comment: Assuming vmware player, if not please retag vmware-workstatio, esx etc. (not vmware itself, unless you want the firm, its employees, shares etc).

Answer (score 3):

1. First off all you have to install/ update the VMware tool (Guest additions)
2. Then create and set the dictionary from your Share Folder in Windwos
3. Now run your virtual machine and open the File Explorer of it. (Navigate to) type in the search/ path bar this: `/mnt/hgfs/mysharedfolder` **<- Path**

An extended discrition you can find [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html).

Answer (score -1):

to find your shared folder using your linux gui explorer go to Filesystem  then hgfs you will find there your folder.

[image]

if you still couldn't find your shared folder so i suspect that this issue occurs because the GCC and PAE kernels are not up to date in the Linux VM and the hgfs folder is not created in the /mnt folder. If so update your kernel and reinstall the vmware tools